# jQuery get accessor

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the canvas element in HTML. But, despite trying the tricks given here on stackoverflow and elsewhere I still run into this:

```
var obj = jQuery('#id')
alert(obj[0])
```

This gives 'undefined', instead of the actual element. Alert(obj) gives 'Object' as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I noticed that I had typoed the example, fixed that now. It still acts wrong. I was expecting obj[0] to give me the DOM element.

EDIT2: Thanks for the comments, it lead me to my answer, which was wrong order of doing things. Had forgotten to use $(document).ready()...

Comment: what do you expect of id[0]? It's defined nowhere in your code snippet...

Comment: Ofcourse it says 'undefined'. `id` doesn't exists.

Comment: I expect it to be the raw element, as pointed out in lots of places.

Comment: if you want the raw element try `obj.get(0)`

Comment: Then either you have a typo in your id too or a duplicate id perhaps. Give `obj.length` a try. If it says 0 you matched no element with your selector

Comment: btw, if you are using a decent browser you will find the javascript console way more helpful for debugging than `alert()`. Use it like this: `console.log(obj)`

Answer (score 2):

You are alerting wrong variable. I think you are looking for this.

```
alert(obj[0]);

var obj = jQuery('#id'); //this will select the element with id = "id"
```

If you want to get the DOM element from `obj` you can access it using `obj[0]` or `obj.get(0)`.

`.get()` retrieves the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the array dereferencing operator to get at the list item instead. So `obj[0]` is same as `obj.get(0)`